# password_verify not working on subdomain in PHP

Tags: php, security, hash, authentication, passwords

I have password_verify working fine on my main site. However, on my subdomain, the exact same code is causing the following error:

**The subdomain.example.com page isn’t working**

**subdomain.example.com is currently unable to handle this request.**

This is my code for verifying the password, `password_verify($password, $hash)`.

Comment: is the primary domain and subdomin on same server and using same version of php?

Comment: Yes, however my .htaccess file for my subdomain contains this line `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php` and my main domain does not. Justhost added that line automatically. I'll try commenting it out now.

Comment: Probably this is the problem. Because you need php 5.5 to use `password_verify`

Comment: Yes it is the problem and it's working now after commenting out that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**password_verify** was only introduced with PHP 5.5 - if your subdomain site is running on a lower version than that, you'll need to use a forwards-compatibility library such as https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: For some reason, JustHost automatically added this line `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php` to the `.htaccess` for my subdomain. I commented it out and it works now.